# Problem HTTP request for KML

Tags: openlayers-2

i have a problem with HTTP request for KML to add to map. This is my HTTP request:

```
var x = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("X", {
    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],

    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({                                    
                url : "../../MyJSP.jsp",                    
                async : false,
                    format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                       extractStyles: true,
                       extractAttributes: true
                     }),

                params : {
                 'request' : 'typeRequest',
                 'param1' : 'a',
         'param2' :'b'                      
            }

            })

        });             


        map.addLayer([x]);
```

The request is send to MyJSP, which make some controls to decide the remote method to invoke:

```
String req = request.getParameter("request")==null ? "" : request.getParameter("request");

if (req.equals("typeRequest")) {    
   String param1= request.getParameter("param1");
   String param2 =   request.getParameter("param2");                
   myClass.myMethod(param1,param2);
```

The request don't arrive here. I think that the problem is the URL `../../MyJSP.jsp`.

```
-forder
 -- folder
 --- folder
       class to make request HTTP 
-MyJsp.jsp
```

Can anybody help me? Thanks.

Comment: what is firebug telling you? are you getting a `404` on the request?